# Sticky sidebar isnt so sticky

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I am using https://rgalus.github.io/sticky-js/ to stick sidebar when user scrolls down.
Structure is as follows:

```js
var sticky = new Sticky('aside');
```

```css
aside {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rgalus.github.io/sticky-js/sticky.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" data-sticky-container>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h2 style="padding-bottom:1400px;margin-bottom:1400">Something here</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <aside>
          <ul>

            <li>Recusandae non impedit aspernatur rem quod quia optio, laboriosam odit ipsam laborum dignissimos alias ea omnis qui eum, ducimus voluptatem, aperiam mollitia nobis reiciendis animi distinctio voluptates doloribus. Accusantium, repellat?</li>
            <li>Recusandae non impedit aspernatur rem quod quia optio, laboriosam odit ipsam laborum dignissimos alias ea omnis qui eum, ducimus voluptatem, aperiam mollitia nobis reiciendis animi distinctio voluptates doloribus. Accusantium, repellat?</li>
            <li>Recusandae non impedit aspernatur rem quod quia optio, laboriosam odit ipsam laborum dignissimos alias ea omnis qui eum, ducimus voluptatem, aperiam mollitia nobis reiciendis animi distinctio voluptates doloribus. Accusantium, repellat?</li>
            <li>Recusandae non impedit aspernatur rem quod quia optio, laboriosam odit ipsam laborum dignissimos alias ea omnis qui eum, ducimus voluptatem, aperiam mollitia nobis reiciendis animi distinctio voluptates doloribus. Accusantium, repellat?</li>
            <li>Recusandae non impedit aspernatur rem quod quia optio, laboriosam odit ipsam laborum dignissimos alias ea omnis qui eum, ducimus voluptatem, aperiam mollitia nobis reiciendis animi distinctio voluptates doloribus. Accusantium, repellat?</li>

          </ul>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Main content area is very tall and sidebar is just a few widgets so making it sticky makes sense. And, it works, sort of. In the sidebar there is image and a post loop which shows 5 posts. In that case, it doesnt work. If i limit post loop to show 4, then it does...
If i replace that post widget with something else, sometimes it work, sometimes it doesnt, it all depends on widget height...

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/wojowi9644/pen/BaobEZB In here it works, but duplicate one more li item and it will stop working... It simply doesnt make any sense.
Console doesnt show any errors and everything should be set up properly

Comment: Please copy your code from CodePen here, in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753), in order to provide a [mre].

Comment: hey @double-beep! just did, try adding 1 more list item and it wont work, then you can see what i mean